# How to make transition in css

Tags: css

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  border: 6px solid red;
  height: 145px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}

.item:hover {
    height: 100%;
}

.footer__item {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__data">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam repudiandae debitis omnis itaque. Dolores quasi aliquid temporibus corporis mollitia sint.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__data">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam repudiandae debitis omnis itaque. Dolores quasi aliquid temporibus corporis mollitia sint.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want, when i hover the item i want to apply the `height: 100%;`. The issue is next: When i hover now, the transition is not applied, but if i change the height  from `100%` to `250px` then the transition is working? Why? And how to apply transition for 100% height?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, this does not solve my issue

Comment: setting the height of container solves it, if thats applicable for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Browers don't support calculations like calculating the height of dynamic elements (usually called *reflow*). Read this article of reference https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/.

Try the below code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  border: 6px solid red;
}

.footer {
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:hover .footer {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.footer__item {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__data">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam repudiandae debitis omnis itaque. Dolores quasi aliquid temporibus corporis mollitia sint.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__data">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam repudiandae debitis omnis itaque. Dolores quasi aliquid temporibus corporis mollitia sint.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
        <div class="footer__item">test</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```